# What are quantum symmetric matrices and quantum exterior matrices?

Tags: representation-theory, quantum-groups

What are quantum symmetric matrices and quantum exterior matrices? I searched google but didn't find the definitions. Thank you very much.

Edit: "algebras of quantum symmetric and quantum exterior matrices" is used in Remark 1.13 of [the paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1007.4357).

Comment: Do you mean quantum symmetric/exterior *algebras*? There is such a thing as quantum symmetric matrices, but I have never heard of quantum exterior matrices myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in Casteels comment, the quantum symmetric algebra is a well-known construction for a $k$-vector space $V$:
$$
S_q(V):=k\langle v_1, \ldots, v_n\mid v_iv_j=q_{ij}v_jv_i\rangle.
$$
(see e.g http://arxiv.org/abs/1111.5243).
Here, the scalars $q_{ij}$ need to satisfy $q_{ii}=1$ and $q_{ji}=q_{ij}^{-1}$. This is sometimes also referred to as the quantum $n$-space (see e.g. http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9905055v1.pdf).

One can also consider a quantum exterior algebra:
$$
\Lambda_q(V):= k\langle v_1,\ldots,v_n\mid v_iv_j+q_{ij}v_jv_i\rangle.$$
(see http://arxiv.org/abs/1111.5243, p.4). Note that this algebra will turn out to be finite-dimensional in characteristic $0$ at least, and $v_i^2=0$ is a consequence from the relations.

These example can be understood in the more general context of *Nichols algebras*.

Comment: thank you very much. I have some questions about three notations of [the paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1007.4357v3.pdf). On page 5, Remark 1.13, what are the definitions of $S_q^2 V$, $S_q(S^2 V)$, $S(S^2 V)$?

Comment: I believe they mean by $S_q^2V$ the degree 2 piece of the algebra $S_q(V)$, i.e the subspace spanned by $v_iv_j$. This is again a vector space. $S(S^2V)$ is the ordinary symmetric algebra of the vector space $S^2V$ defined in the same way in the classical case. For $S_q(S^2V)$ please try following up on the reference the paper gives:  [9, 19, 14, 22] in the same remark. It will hopefully be clear from there.

Comment: This question makes sense in a different way now as I see the reference to the Berenstein--Greenstein paper, where they use the term "algebras of quantum symmetric and
quantum exterior matrices". Would have been very helpful to cite that paper in the question.

Comment: I think that it should be possible to understand  $S_q(S^2V)$ as the quantum symmetric algebra on the larger vector space $S^2 V$, but I don't see which $q_{ij}$ are used then. The references (e.g. [22] Strickland) seem to give the algebra directly with generators and relations. Hence there is something to check to make the connection. This question, properly formulated, would be research level and maybe better to be ask on mathoverflow?

Comment: thank you very much. I have cite the paper in the question.